# Connecting mysql java connector to AWS Aurora Via SSL from a EMR Cluster: One approach

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-emr, amazon-aurora

How to connect a job form a EMR cluster to a Aurora via SSL? There is a lot of information scattered on forums that brings partial solution to this issue so I'm trying to summarize up here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information about connecting to AWS Aurora Via SSL from mysql java connector scattered on forums and also stackoverflow, so apologies if I don't include all the references.

Long story short: There are two main issues connecting a program running in a EMR Cluster to Aurora with ssl:

1) Just importing the rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem provided by Amazon to a keystore won't work as it'll show an "PKIX path building failed" error.

2) The java property javax.net.ssl.keyStore won't be available from the cluster's slaves so the app will not find the keyStore an it will produce a "Communications link failure"

The cause for 1) seems to be related to the fact that the file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem has several certificates so in a forum that I don't have the reference now, the proposed solution was to split these certificates. The certificate for Aurora is the 8th:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIID/DCCAuSgAwIBAgIBQzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBijELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
>   EzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xEDAOBgNVBAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxIjAgBgNVBAoM
>   GUFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMx
>   GzAZBgNVBAMMEkFtYXpvbiBSRFMgUm9vdCBDQTAeFw0xNTAyMDUyMTU0MDRaFw0y
>   MDAzMDUyMTU0MDRaMIGPMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3Rv
>   bjEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTEiMCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNl
>   cywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1hem9uIFJEUzEgMB4GA1UEAwwXQW1hem9uIFJE
>   UyB1cy1lYXN0LTEgQ0EwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDI
>   UIuwh8NusKHk1SqPXcP7OqxY3S/M2ZyQWD3w7Bfihpyyy/fc1w0/suIpX3kbMhAV
>   2ESwged2/2zSx4pVnjp/493r4luhSqQYzru78TuPt9bhJIJ51WXunZW2SWkisSaf
>   USYUzVN9ezR/bjXTumSUQaLIouJt3OHLX49s+3NAbUyOI8EdvgBQWD68H1epsC0n
>   CI5s+pIktyOZ59c4DCDLQcXErQ+tNbDC++oct1ANd/q8p9URonYwGCGOBy7sbCYq
>   9eVHh1Iy2M+SNXddVOGw5EuruvHoCIQyOz5Lz4zSuZA9dRbrfztNOpezCNYu6NKM
>   n+hzcvdiyxv77uNm8EaxAgMBAAGjZjBkMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjASBgNVHRMB
>   Af8ECDAGAQH/AgEAMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQSQG3TmMe6Sa3KufaPBa72v4QFDzAfBgNV
>   HSMEGDAWgBROAu6sPvYVyEztLPUFwY+chAhJgzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEA
>   L/mOZfB3187xTmjOHMqN2G2oSKHBKiQLM9uv8+97qT+XR+TVsBT6b3yoPpMAGhHA
>   Pc7nxAF5gPpuzatx0OTLPcmYucFmfqT/1qA5WlgCnMNtczyNMH97lKFTNV7Njtek
>   jWEzAEQSyEWrkNpNlC4j6kMYyPzVXQeXUeZTgJ9FNnVZqmvfjip2N22tawMjrCn5
>   7KN/zN65EwY2oO9XsaTwwWmBu3NrDdMbzJnbxoWcFWj4RBwanR1XjQOVNhDwmCOl
>   /1Et13b8CPyj69PC8BOVU6cfTSx8WUVy0qvYOKHNY9Bqa5BDnIL3IVmUkeTlM1mt
>   enRpyBj+Bk9rh/ICdiRKmA==
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

So if you extract this segment in a file called, let's say bundle8.pem, you generate your key as follows:

```
keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file bundle8.pem -keystore truststore
```

The solution for 2) is to set javax.net.ssl.keyStore as a command parameter, for the case of spark-submit, the option should be '--driver-java-options':

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --driver-java-options='-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore' --files s3://path/to/truststore ..other spark options
```

Being "truststore" the file generated with the keytool. The --driver-java-options will allow the truststore file to be available on the slaves's environments.

Reference:

Connecting to an Amazon Aurora DB Cluster:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connect.html

Connecting Mysql Java Connector Using SSL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html